# How to Avoid Running a New Thread If a Thread Already Exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I need to run an X thread once and stop spawning new threads if X thread is still running. For example, assume my thread is initiated from within a function called start_my_thread().

start_my_thread() initiates a thread for kline_func, which listens from a remote server and runs indefinitely assuming no network interruption happens.

```
def kline_func():
    ...
    ...
    ...

    while True:
       pass

def start_my_thread():
    kline_thread = Thread(target = kline_func)
    kline_thread.start()

start_my_thread() # first call
start_my_thread() # second call
start_my_thread() # third call
```

My question is how do I make sure kline_thread.start() is called once only no matter how many times I call start_my_thread(). In other words, whenever we call start_my_thread(), I want to check do we have an existing running kline_thread thread or not. If we don't, trigger kline_thread.start(). If we already have kline_thread running, don't trigger kline_thread.start().

I'm using Python3.x. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `threading.enumerate()` function, as described in the doc :

> Return a list of all Thread objects currently active. The list
> includes daemonic threads and dummy thread objects created by
> current_thread(). It excludes terminated threads and threads that have
> not yet been started. However, the main thread is always part of the
> result, even when terminated

We set the thread name when initializing the Thread object

```
def kline_func():
    ...
    ...
    ...

    while True:
       pass

def start_my_thread():

    thread_names = [t.name for t in threading.enumerate()]
 
    if "kline_thread" not in thread_names:
        kline_thread = Thread(target = kline_func, name="kline_thread")
        kline_thread.start()


start_my_thread() # first call
start_my_thread() # second call
start_my_thread() # third call
```