# Preventing multiple instances of a thread in GTK

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

Upon pressing a listbox row, a thread is started which:

1. Clears the treeview (its liststore)
2. Then, adds items to the treeview (or rather its liststore).

The row can be pressed multiple times, meaning it can spawn multiple threads, which may end up running simultaneously.

The issue is that if the row is pressed very quickly multiple times, the treeview ends up with duplicate entries. This is caused by the multiple threads running in parallel, all trying to add the same set of items the treeview.

The solution to this issue would be to only ever allow one instance of the thread running at any time. This could be done by either:

- Preventing new thread instances from starting if the thread is currently running
- Stop the already running instance of the thread, and only then starting a new one

**The problem is that I do not know how to implement either of those solutions.**

Code:

```
class Main(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView()
        self.treeview.set_model(self.liststore)
        cellrenderertext = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        treeviewcolumn = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Items", cellrenderertext, text=0)
        self.treeview.append_column(treeviewcolumn)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label='Button')

        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)

        box.add(self.button)
        box.add(self.treeview)
        self.add(box)

        self.button.connect('clicked', self.button_clicked)


    def button_clicked(self, widget):
        def threaded():
            self.liststore.clear()
            self.liststore.append(['first_item'])
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.liststore.append(['second_item'])
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.liststore.append(['third_item'])

        threading.Thread(target=threaded, daemon=True).start()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Main()
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

I added the `time.sleep(0.1)` to simulate the delay between each item being added.
Pressing the button multiple times will result in duplicate entries appearing in the treeview. The expected output is:

`first_item`

`second_item`

`third_item`

However, pressing the button really quickly instead results in:

`first_item`

`third_item`

`second_item`

`third_item`

Comment: You can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73004900/10556711 answer

Comment: you should use variable to keep thread and check this variable. Set at start `self.thread =None` and later do `if not self.thread or not self.thread.is_alive(): self.thread = threading.Thread(...)` `self.thread.start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use variable to keep thread and check this variable.

In `__init__` set variable

```
self.thread = None
```

and when you press button then check this variable

```
#if (self.thread in None) or (self.thread.is_alive() is False): 
if not self.thread or not self.thread.is_alive(): 
    self.thread = threading.Thread(...) 
    self.thread.start()
```

---

Instead of checking `is_alive()` you could set `self.thread = None` at the end of thread.

Comment: this method is popular also to create some widgets/object only once - and when you delete widget/object then you set again `variable = None` and you can create again this object.

Comment: there is also other method: you can deactivate button so it will not run function - and thread would have to activate button again at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Note that all of the comments or answers that tell you how do deal with threading in Python might be partially correct for the narrow question on multi-threading, but they're not really what you want here.

You should realize that almost all the GTK/GLib API (like `Gtk.ListStore`) is **not** thread-safe unless explicitly mentioned. If you're going to call those functions from different threads than the main one, you should be prepared to encounter random and hard-to-debug issues.

In this case, if you want to update your Gtk.ListStore from a different thread, you want to make sure you use a function like [`GLib.idle_add()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GLib-2.0/functions.html#GLib.idle_add) to update the store in the main thread.

You might also want to read up on the [PyGObject tutorial on threading and concurrency](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. To be honest, I would usually use `GLib.idle_add` with most GTK related code, however I was quite unsure about whether to use it with`Gtk.ListStore`, since it modifies a model and not the UI directly - but as it appears this distinction is irrelevant. On that matter, any idea whether GTK code that checks the status of widgets is thread-safe (such as `Gtk.Button.get_label`)?

Comment: Also not thread-safe. If it doesn't get _explicitly_ mentioned, any API you use isn't thread safe.